# How to use Navigation Safe Args with Kotlinx serializable data

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlinx.serialization, android-safe-args

I'm trying to use Navigation Safe Args with Kotlinx @Serializable types, but I keep getting the same issue during run-time when I pass the serializable data:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.serializablesafeargsnavigation.shared.Model.SerializableModel is not Serializable or Parcelable.
```

In my *nav_graph.xml* I have the following:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.serializablesafeargsnavigation.androidApp.FirstFragment"
        android:label="FirstFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.serializablesafeargsnavigation.androidApp.SecondFragment"
        android:label="SecondFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="arg"
            app:argType="com.example.serializablesafeargsnavigation.shared.Model.SerializableModel" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

My *SerializableModel* looks like this:

```
@Serializable
data class SerializableModel(
    @SerialName("some_value")
    val someValue: String
)
```

Has anybody found a workaround to make this work with Safe Args. It works if you pass a Bundle with the navigate API, but I would like to use Safe Args if possible.

Versions I'm using

- plugin.serialization: 1.4.21
- navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin: 2.3.2
- androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx: 2.3.2
- androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx: 2.3.2
- kotlinx-serialization-core: 1.0.1

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Please share some code, so that it could be understood.

Comment: @rahat Thanks for the input! I updated the post with some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your model is in the shared module, probably you won't be able to use *jvm* and *android* dependencies.

You can create your own parcelize `expect/actual` abstraction or you could use [moko-parcelize](https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-parcelize), which essentially does the same

Answer (score 4):

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.serializablesafeargsnavigation.shared.Model.SerializableModel is not Serializable or Parcelable.

What you need to extend is Marker interface `java.io.Serializable` or `android.os.Parcelable` which are necessary for data transfer with activities/ fragments.

```
@Serializable
data class SerializableModel(
    @SerialName("some_value")
    val someValue: String
):java.io.Serializable
```

Answer (score 1):

The new **Kotlinx** `Serializable` is designed to work with transmitting data between your app and its backend (cloud server), **Not For Transmitting Data Within Android App.** See offcial answer [here](https://twitter.com/murtazakhussain/status/1060237821405995015).

For transmitting data within **Android app**, use **Kotlin** `Parcelable` with `Parcelize` plguin, see [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize):

```
@Parcelize        //add annotaion for simplifing parcelizing process
data class MarsProperty(
    val id: String,
    val type: String,
    val price: Double
) : Parcelable    //implement Parcelable interface, 【must have to be recognized as Custom Parcelable object in safe args】
```